# Finding if n is a factorial number in Java

Tags: java, factorial

I'm trying to find if n is a factorial number but I think my code is wrong on the cycle for):

```
static boolean fatorial(int n){

    for (int a = 2; a < n; a = a * (a+1)){
        if (n/a == 1){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What is a "factorial number"? You mean fibonacci?

Comment: The values of `a` will be 2, 6, 42... not sure that it is what you wanted.

Comment: a=a*(a+1) is wrong

Comment: What results do you expect and what result do you get? (For different n)?

Comment: @cricket_007 factorial number of n (also written `n!`) is `1 * 2 * 3 * ... * n`

Comment: n/a == 1 implies that n is anything from a to 2a-1. Was that your intent?

Comment: @cricket_007 for example: 120 is a factorial number because 120 = 5!

Comment: `for (int a = 2; n % a == 0; n /= a++) {} return n == 1;`.

Comment: I think `n/a == 1` can also fail, e.g. for `n=3`, because of integer division. Better create factorial numbers up to `n` and return true if you hit `n`, or false if not. Number of steps is the same, but using multiplication (cheaper than division).

Comment: @AndyTurner You should post this as an answer with a bit of explanation. It is very elegant btw.

Answer (score 4):

a = a*(a+1) will start from a = 2 then a = 2*3 = 6 then a = 6*7 = 42..

```
static boolean fatorial(int n){
    long res = 1;
    int i = 2;
    while(res < n) {
       res = res * i++;
    }
    return res == n; // if res == n that means n was a factorial (res is always a factorial)
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to increment `i`?

Comment: @Vasan missed that!

Comment: Easy to understand, probably faster than using division, and no hassle with integer division. +1

Comment: @AndyTurner didn't get you. 1932053505 isn't a factorial and the program returns false. where's the overflow?

Comment: @mehulmpt apologies - I hadn't spotted you were using `long res`; there will be no overflow because of that. Ignore the 1932053505, I was copying some output without thinking about it.

Comment: @AndyTurner no problem :)

Answer (score 2):

You can write this as:

```
for (int a = 2; n % a == 0; n /= a++) {}
return n == 1;
```

If the empty for loop body makes you uncomfortable:

```
int a = 2;
while (n % a == 0) {
  n /= a;
  a++;
}
return n == 1;
```

To explain:

- Check if `n` is divisible by `a`, which will have the values 2, 3, 4, 5 ...
- If it isn't divisible by that number, `n` wasn't a factorial in the first place
- If it is divisible, divide `n` by that number (so you don't count those factors again in a subsequent check (*)), and increase `a`.

If `n == 1` at the end, you didn't break the loop early, and it was a factorial initially.

---

(*) For instance, `600 = 2*3*4*5*5` isn't a factorial, but it is divisible by 6, because of the `2*3`. Dividing by 2 and 3 after you've found it is divisible by those means you don't accidentally count it again.